# Architecture Design: Separating Apps and Interacting by Way of APIs

Tags: architecture

I'm creating an entire website that will me a conglomeration of a bunch of smaller sites.  Naturally they're all interrelated, but different people will log into different sections for different reasons.

One thing I'm trying to get away from is a a monolithic architecture, I like the idea of breaking up everything into subprojects so one team can work on one project, one team can work on another project, etc.

My question:  I'm hearing more and more people doing interproject communications by way of restful APIs rather than having direct access to the database.

For instance:

```
                app 4 
                  |
app1 ----->   central core <------app2
                  |
                app 3
```

so apps 1-4 would communicate with a central core by way of APIs.  They would have their own individual models for their own specific applications, but a central core would contain the bulk of the application.

My question:  Is it correct implementation to go about this design, or should I just stick with the traditional monolithic project which contains one model implementation?

Where can I get examples of good system architecture?

Thanks

Comment: An option would be to read up on DDD (domain driven design) and specifically bounded contexts and context maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no doubt that abstracting the functionality into API is the right way to go to reduce the maintenance overhead. You should see a project like llvm.

The problem which comes with breaking your application into a "core" and a "driver" is, that the software upgrade gets a little tricky. Because now you have to upgrade both core and driver  together. That is the biggest issue in shipping software as a library. If core is old and driver is new then it will not work.

But I do not think this is an issue for you.

THere are many good books on software design.